# Help to understand that $x\left( z\right) ={Re}\int_{z_{0}}^{z}\phi \left( \xi \right) d\xi $ is well defined

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\phi :\Omega \subset 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
$ holomorphic function. Define $x:\Omega \subset 
\rightarrow 
\mathbb{C}
$ by $x\left( z\right) ={Re}\int_{z_{0}}^{z}\phi \left( \xi \right)
d\xi $.

The author states:
"It is not necessary that the domain $\Omega$ is simply connected, but only that the periods  (that is, that the integral along any closed curve) $\phi_k$ are pure imaginary so that the functions $x_k$ are well defined."

Because for $x_k$ is well defined, just enough?
I can not understand. For me if the integral is pure imaginary, then the function $x_k$ will be identically zero.

Could someone help me to understand this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't say that the integral from $z_0$ to $z$ is purely imaginary, but that the integral *along a closed curve* must be purely imaginary.

This means that if you have two *different* curves that both go from $z_0$ to $z$, the *difference* of their integrals will equal the integral around a closed curve (namely, out from $z_0$ to $z$ along one curve and back again along the other) will be purely imaginary, and therefore the two integrals have the same *real* part.